# Are questions about the Vitae Researcher Development Framework on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a fairly specific question about how a common activity for academics (reviewing grants) maps onto to the [Researcher Development Framework](https://www.vitae.ac.uk/researchers-professional-development/about-the-vitae-researcher-development-framework) run by [Vitae](https://www.vitae.ac.uk/). Is this too narrow for Academia? Vitae claims to be "the global leader in supporting the professional development of researchers" but I don't really have a good feel for how widely they're known within or outside the UK; we only started using the RDF recently.

Comment: The answer is "it depends."  What are you actually wanting to ask?

Comment: Reviewing grants, as it says in my question. Essentially, "Where does grant reviewing fit into the Vitae RDF"? The only area I can find that seems to match is phase 1 of C3 "Income & funding generation" ("I understand the processes for funding and evaluation of research"), but I would say reviewing large grants from multiple funders is typically something you aren't invited to do until you're fairly well established and have some reputation in an area, so I would expect it to map onto phase 3 or 4 somewhere.

Comment: It might also fit under 3-4 of this topic ("I understand funding complexities and the variety of sources for funding") but this still doesn't really seem a good match for grant reviewing, which is odd as I'd consider reviewing grants a core activity for researchers. Both of these seem more intended to relate to your own grant applications.

Comment: I could identify a few other possible matches, but that doesn't seem appropriate for Meta - this is turning into the actual question now.

Comment: I think this question would be OK, as long as you make it clear that you're trying to understand how to fit yourself onto this framework (or whatever the motivation is), not asking for an authoritative interpretation.

Comment: Okay, thanks - I'll give it a shot on the main site. Do you want to expand that a bit and post it as an answer?

Comment: I have thoughts on an answer, but they'll require a little more looking at the source material.

Comment: Gah - never mind; just noticed peer review appears as a phase 3 activity under 'reputation and esteem'. I am an idiot (although in my defence the RDF site could do with a better search function).